# Email has different ip for sendor when it ends up in spam than when it ends up in inbox. How?

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-20.04, laravel

I have a simple vps server that i'm using to send confirmation emails from.

The problem is that sometimes when i send a confirmation email it ends up in spam with sender ip different than the ip of a sender when it ends up in inbox.

When i type `hostname -I` in cli i get two ips, one v4 the other v6(i think):

```
78.xx.xxx.xxx 2a01:xxx:xxx:4c9b::1
```

The first one ends up in inbox, the second one ends up in spam.

This is my spf record value:

```
v=spf1 a mx ip4:78.xx.xxx.xxx ip6:2a01:xxx:xxx:4c9b::1 include:zoho.eu ~all
```

When it ends up in `inbox` it looks like this (gmail):

```
SPF:    PASS with IP 78.xx.xxx.xxx
DKIM:   'PASS' with domain example.com 
DMARC:  'PASS'
```

When it ends up in `spam` it looks like this (gmail):

```
SPF:    PASS with IP 2a01:xxx:xxx:4c9b:0:0:0:1 
DKIM:   'PASS' with domain example.com
DMARC:  'PASS'
```

Also when it ends up in spam this is what Google prompts me with:

```
It is similar to messages that were identified as spam in the past.
```

I am using `Postfix` and `Laravel 7` and the default template for email confirmation from Laravel. I have all the records that Google asked for (spf, dkim, dmarc).

Is the problem coming from having two ips when i type `hostname -I`? Is it coming from Laravel's default template?

What should i do? What can i do? Thank you!

Comment: Did you set PTR records on both of your IP addresses? Your VPS provider should give a control panel where this can be done.

Comment: @MichaelHampton hey, i have root access and a dns console, but i have no idea what a PTR record is (threfore i don't have those records set). Can you provide some additional info? :-?

Comment: It is the DNS record which gives a name for your IP address. Your provider might also call it "reverse DNS".

Comment: I found a thing in my dashboard that looks like this: `ip: 78.xx... rDNS: server.xyz...` and then  my ipv6 has no reverse dns and looks like this `ip: 2a01:xxx:xxx:4c9b::/64 rDNS: none`. Should i point that ipv6 to the same rDNS as that ipv4? :-?

Comment: Yes, it should have the same name as your mail server hostname.

Comment: There is no conflict if both ips point to the same rDNS or stuff like that? ^.^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111516/discussion-between-emma-and-michael-hampton).